# can cURL operations be inside the API server side code?

Tags: php

I see an example server side API that has cURL operations, I thought cURL is supposedly client side request. The following class API is the server side code but inherited from newtwork class which has a bunch of uCurls operations.

> class Api extends Api\Network
>
> ```
> abstract class Network {
> const GET  = 'GET';
> const POST = 'POST';
>
> const HTTP_OK      = 200;
> const HTTP_CREATED = 201;
>
> protected function curl($type, $url, $queryString = array())
> {
>     $s = curl_init();
>     switch (strtoupper($type)) {
>         case self::POST:
>             echo "$url\n";
>             echo \http_build_query($queryString) . "\n";
>                 die();
>             curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
>             curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, true);
>             curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $queryString);
>             break;
>         case self::GET:
>             curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '?' .
> ```
>
> http_build_query($queryString));
>                   break;
>           }
>
> ```
>     curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>     $_out = curl_exec($s);
>     $status = curl_getinfo($s, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
>     curl_close($s);
>     switch ($status) {
>         case self::HTTP_OK:
>         case self::HTTP_CREATED:
>             $out = $_out;
>             break;
>         default:
>             throw new \Exception("http error: {$status}",
> ```
>
> $status);
>           }
>           return $out;
>       } }

Comment: This is so the server side API can in turn make calls to other servers and POST/GET information to them. Say there is a server that provides Geographical IP lookup (there are a few). Your server wants to do geolocate its visitors. It can use this server side API with curl to post to the geo location db server and find the result.

Comment: Yep sure you can do server side cURL call, just need the right extension.

Comment: OK, arunkumar, that make sense it trying calling other server.

Comment: http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/   how about this one?    $return_obj     = new RestRequest(); inside the processrequest.   This RestRequest is a client request object in it's code it has a bunch of cURLs.  However, in this case, the API server doesn't call another server.

Comment: Curl would always be a server-side action - your average web server is NOT going to have curl installed on their home desktop machine.

Answer (score 1):

cURL can be used serverside too, if you have the correct php extension installed.

Comment: http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/   how about this one?    $return_obj     = new RestRequest(); inside the prcoessrequest    This RestRequest is a client request object in it's code it has a bunch of cURLs.  However, in this case, the API server doesn't call another server.